# Animation playback in sceneform does not work (ArCore)

Tags: android, blender, arcore, sceneform

I am creating an AR app with https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/sceneform-android-sdk and use this code to add the model to the scene:

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(this, R.raw.olaf)
        .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
        .build()
        .thenAccept(modelRenderable ->
        {
        mainAnchorNode = new AnchorNode(startAnchor);
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(mainAnchorNode);

        TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        transformableNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1f, 0), 180f));

        transformableNode.setParent(mainAnchorNode);
        transformableNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
}
```

In blender I created five animations:

[image]

I am trying to play animation like this (where animationType is names from blender e.x.: "olaf_walk", "olaf_hello"):

```
private ObjectAnimator animator;

animator = ModelAnimator.ofAnimation(transformableNode.getRenderableInstance(), animationType);
animator.start();
```

But when I switch animation to the next one (with button), the previous keep playing, and the new animation doesn't start playing.

I try to cancel, stop, pause animator, created a new animator for each animation but no results.

How can I switch between different animations in sceneform?